# Deleting old files is slow and 'kills' IO performance

Tags: linux, debian, ext4

I'm using find to prune old files, lots of them.. this takes minutes / hours to run and other server processes encounter IO performance issues.

```
find -mtime +100 -delete -print
```

I tried ionice but it didn't appear to help.

```
ionice -c 3
```

What can one do to 1. speed up the find operation and 2. to avoid impacting other processes?
The FS is ext4.. is ext4 just bad at this kind of workload?
Kernel is 3.16
Storage is 2x 1TB 7200rpm HDDs in RAID 1.
There's 93GB in 610228 files now, so 152KB/file on average.

Maybe I just shouldn't store so many files in a single directory?

Comment: Add to the post, how many files, and disk technology, please.

Answer (score 2):

When you run the `find` command like you posted, it will do a `rm` for each file that it finds. This isn't a good way to do it, in terms of performance.

For improve this task, you can use the `-exec` option in find for process the output to a `rm` command:

```
find -mtime +100 -exec rm {} +
```

It's very important the use of the `+` termination instead the alternate `\;`. With `+`, find will only make a `rm` command for the maximum number of files it can process on a simple execution. With the `\;` termination, `find` will do a `rm` command for each file, so you would have the same problem.

For a better performance, you can join it to the `ionice` command like you mentioned. If you don't notice that it improves the system performance, most possible is that it is consuming other resources more than I/O, like CPU. For this, you can use `renice` command to decrease the priority in CPU usage of the process.

I would use the following:

```
ionice -c 3 find -mtime +100 -exec rm {} +
```

Now, in another shell, you need to find the PID of the find command: `ps -ef | grep find`

And finally run the renice command: `renice +19 -p <PID_find_command>`

Comment: why not use `xargs` so that each spawn of a `rm` process deletes, say, 50 files at a time ?

Comment: Using `xargs` will not work with files with blank spaces in the filename. You need to pay attention to build the comand with `-print0` option that process the blank spaces, something like `find -mtime +100 -print0 | xargs -0 rm`. This complicates the execution of the command and will not work out of the box with the I/O performance modification in one single command, like in the example of `ionice` with `find` and `-exec`. Also, using `xargs` doesn't offer a better performance than using `find` with `-exec` and `+` termination, so I prefer this last option.

Comment: Does -exec take care of spaces and other weird stuff? As we're IO bound, how does using rm improve performance?